# CORBA C++: undefined reference to `CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(CORBA::Object*)'

Tags: c++, corba

i get a the following fault:

```
'undefined reference to `CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow(CORBA::Object*)'
```

Here the function to register the server:

```
void registerServer(CORBA::ORB_var obj){


CORBA::Object_var nsobj = obj->resolve_initial_references("NameService");
CosNaming::NamingContext_var nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow (nsobj);

if (CORBA::is_nil (nc)) {
    cerr << "Fehler: Konnte Naming Service nicht erreichen!" << endl;
    exit (1);
}

// Naming Service fuer unser Konto einrichten
CosNaming::Name name; 
name.length (1);
name[0].id = CORBA::string_dup ("VMS");
name[0].kind = CORBA::string_dup ("");
name[1].id = CORBA::string_dup("VMS_Context");
name[1].kind = CORBA::string_dup("");



cout << "VMS wird an Naming Service gebunden ... " << flush;
try{
 CosNaming::NamingContext_var namingContext = nc->bind_new_context(name);
}
catch(CosNaming::NamingContext::AlreadyBound_catch &ex){
    //darf ignoriert werden
}
cout << "done." << endl;
```

}

here the funcitoncall in main:

```
CORBA::ORB_var orb = CORBA::ORB_init(argc, argv, "omniORB3");

  CORBA::Object_var poaobj = orb->resolve_initial_references("RootPOA");

  PortableServer::POA_var poa = PortableServer::POA::_narrow( poaobj);
  PortableServer::POAManager_var mgr = poa->the_POAManager();

  //My Object

  VMSRepository_i* myVMSRepository = new VMSRepository_i (100, 10);

  PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid = poa->activate_object(myVMSRepository);

  CORBA::Object_var ref = poa->id_to_reference(oid.in());


   registerServer(orb);
```

the fault is caused by:

```
CosNaming::NamingContext_var nc = CosNaming::NamingContext::_narrow (nsobj);
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the TAO ORB... is that right?

In that case it looks like you need to check your paths and make sure you have your tao.lib etc... included somewhere that your linker can find it.

Comment: FYI, TAO as C++ ORB does support OpenVMS